# Sound is not played in push notifications

Tags: ios, ios7

I am using iOS 7 and my push notifications do not play sounds.

Strangely, I found there is no setting for sound in the Preference > Notification Center for my app. Following is the screenshots of Notification center for my app:
[image]

And following is that for Skype:

[image]

You see, there is no 'Sounds' section for my app.

Could anyone help?

---

Update:

Now I have registered sound in my app. The Notification Center now looks like:
[image]

and my notification has sounds. Looks good.

But after I enter the setting of my app, there is initially a 'Sounds' section like Skype, but then the Preference app crashed, and after that, there is no more 'Sounds', just like below:
[image]

Might it be a bug of Apple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not registered for audio push notifications in your app. Just register for it like this in your App Delegate:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Whatever you have already in your app delegate...

    // Let device know you're going to be sending one of these types of notifications.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

The 5 types are:

1. UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
2. UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
3. UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert
4. UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone
5. UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability

Here's the documentation: [Registering for Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIRemoteNotificationType)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works! But still a little problem. Please refer to my updated post:)

Comment: Try to delete your app and reinstall it. Some aspects of push notifications are not updated otherwise (I don't recall which now, but I've had similar issues).